# How to track pyqt5 crash errors?

Tags: pyqt5

I use QWebEngineView to log in to the telegram web.
I would like to be able to save the session in the profile.
When I try to load a profile with an authorized session, my application abruptly terminates.

Is there anything I can do to track the errors that occurred during startup?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        profile = QWebEngineProfile(f"profile", self.browser)
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, self.browser)
        self.browser.setPage(webpage)
        self.browser.load(QUrl('https://web.telegram.org/z'))
        self.browser.show()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    MyApp.exec_()
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#QWebEngineProfile-1), "A disk-based QWebEngineProfile should be destroyed on or before application exit, otherwise the cache and persistent data may not be fully flushed to disk." According to your code, the `self.browser` object has no Qt relation with the `Window` instance (which doesn't make a lot of sense). Maybe the browser object (and its profile) get destroyed abruptly, preventing proper saving of the profile. I would start by making a proper parenthood relation and see what happens in that case.

Comment: You're right. As always, though)) That solved the problem.